# Next file is created before completion of the First file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, buffer, fopen, fputs

in Php i have written a code like below

```
//Example Code

foreach($arrayitem as $arr) //$arrayitem is having some array data
{
 $fp=fopen($arr.'.xls','w');

 for(condition)
 {
  //here i'm getting full content of an webpage(huge data) and some regexp to match data

  preg_match(regexp,getContent of an URL,$output);

  fputs($fp,$output);
 }
fclose($fp);
}
```

The idea here is to create a file and write the data in the `$output` variable and then creating the second file and writing the $output in that file and so on up-to the all values in the 
`$arrayitem` get finishes.

- but what i have observed is that the second file and other
  consecutive files are getting created before the completion of the first file
- And the file size is increasing slowly(on refresh the file size is
  changing)

how this can be possible ? 
what is actually happening here? 
normally the next file should be created only after completion of the first file right?

Comment: If you can, I'd consider collecting all the data for a single file in one go and then writing with `file_put_contents`.  It's simpler code, particularly when you add in exception handling to deal with possible dangling file handles.  Obviously this would depend on the size of files you're writing, etc.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but i want to know why it is happening like that?